# Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 upgrade to 20.04 fails

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, services, udev

My server is driving me nuts, I'm trying to change the current hdd to a new ssd and after that setting up Raid and a valid backup system.  But that's other question...

I already made a copy of the current system to the SSD, so I thought, it's a backup, let me try to put in the latest LTS, so the quick command to do that was:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Fails with the message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release  
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

So i had to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first time it installed a bunch of things and stopped or I had to restart, don't remember very well did this in the past. Now I have this error, when I run the upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
 lxd : Depends: lxd-client (= 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 1:0.9 is installed  
 lxd-client : Depends: lxd (>= 1:0.9) but 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I did what the message says:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And new error:

```
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.10) ...  
Failed to restart udev.service: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
See system logs and 'systemctl status udev.service' for details.  
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.  
 systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager  
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)  
   Active: inactive (dead)  
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)  
           man:udev(7)  
Aug 12 11:36:10 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 11:39:00 AtomServer systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
Aug 12 11:41:35 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 11:41:35 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 11:41:35 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 11:41:35 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:00:56 AtomServer systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
Aug 12 12:00:59 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:00:59 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:01:00 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):  
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:  
 snapd depends on udev; however:  
  Package udev is not configured yet.  
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.                                                                                                      Errors were encountered while processing:  
 udev  
 snapd  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At this point I can't do anything, read several posts and similar questions, issued some commands, like:

```
dpkg --configure -a 
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_245.4-4ubuntu3.10_amd64.deb
```

Same problem:

```
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.10) ...  
Failed to restart udev.service: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
See system logs and 'systemctl status udev.service' for details.  
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.  
 systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager  
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)  
   Active: inactive (dead)  
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)  
           man:udev(7)  
Aug 12 12:00:59 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:01:00 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:09:00 AtomServer systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
Aug 12 12:10:38 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:10:38 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:10:38 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:11:50 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:11:51 AtomServer systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit systemd-udevd.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.  
Aug 12 12:11:51 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
Aug 12 12:11:51 AtomServer systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26: Executable path is not absolute: udevadm control --reload --timeout 0  
dpkg: error processing package udev (--install):  
 installed udev package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1  
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.44) ...  
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...  
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 udev
```

Any help?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Output apt-get update:

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Fetched 328 kB in 2s (140 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: I would `sudo apt update` and look at what output you get.  Your installed packages don't match a single release; some matching *bionic/updates* and others matching *focal/universe*. It would help if you'd used {code} formatting and not quoting (in your question; it's hard to read), and if you were clear with what you actually did.. Either way I'd start with by reading the output of `sudo apt update` & scanning your sources.  Why are you trying to install that version of `udev` as it's outdated! and not a currently used package for *focal* or *focal-updates*; again `sudo apt update` & why?

Comment: Could you add output of `file /usr/bin/udevadm` please?

Comment: @guiverc
At this point I don't know what I'm doing... To many tests.
The udev version that I'm trying to install it's something that I read somewhere... :/
Edited my question with the output of the Update.
Thanks

Comment: @ExploitFate I don't have that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**:

Looks like you trying to install wrong udev version. For [bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/udev) download and install `http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/udev_237-3ubuntu10.50_amd64.deb`

You can try to comment out line `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service:26`    till upgrade will be finished

```
sudo sed -i '/ExecReload/s/.*/#\0/g' /lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service


sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Than try to upgrade once again

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks
Disabled the line in the file and after that installed the package. When I tried to run the do-release-upgrade, it said that I need to install the pending updates. So run apt upgrade, and I got new errors complaining about the lxd-client package e lxd, so I used the same techinque, and download the deb files and forced the installation with the 
dpkg. Now it's installing all updates... Let's see how it ends.

Comment: Problem solved.
20.04 installed 
Thanks

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: works on debian too

Comment: You don't need to comment the line, the issue is the path of `ExecReload` is not absolute
just replace `ExecReload=udevadm` with `ExecReload=/bin/udevadm`